# Visual Studio 2019 16.6.2 100% cpu usage when open any project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Am I alone who got this problem after few last updates?
I've tried to reinstall VS/Winblows as well, nothing changed.
VS 2017 works well but I need 142 toolset (:
I even have huge lag moving main menu window.

I'm on windows 8.1 sl, how can I diagnose the cause and what info I should attach?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfLAa.png

Upd:
My PC:
CPU: intel i5-4460
RAM: 16GB HyperX
GPU: GeForce 745 2GB

Comment: Can you share the system configuration of your PC?

Comment: known issue and they gave us a work around in this article https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/visual-studio-2019-162-high-cpu-usage/668242